# libxml2 - xmlNodeSetContent and entities trouble

Tags: html, objective-c, xml, libxml2, entities

I'm making an application for iOS which uses libxml2 to generate some XML which is later used as a SOAP request. I wrote a recursive function which takes a NSDictionary as a parameter and generates XML nodes according to its nested structure (I allow a NSDictionary to be set as a value in another NSDictionary). I ran into a situation where it is not enough and I want to manually create some XML and then put it inside of a certain node. I found out that it is not possible using my current code.

libxml2 automatically substitutes all special characters, including `<` and `>` that are obviously essential, with their HTML entity correspondents - like `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Even though I've read on the web that I need to encode them manually - using xmlEncodeEntitiesReentrant. I'm pretty clueless. All I need to do is to temporarily disable that substitution in order to put some clean XML code into a node.

Here's a snippet from my application's source:

```
void generate_xml(xmlNodePtr root, NSDictionary *dict) {
    for (NSString *key in dict) {
        xmlNodePtr node = NULL;
        id obj = [dict valueForKey:key];

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            node = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST [key UTF8String]);
            xmlAddChild(root, node);
            generate_xml(node, obj);
        } else if ([key isEqual:@"text"]) {
            xmlNodeSetContent(root, BAD_CAST [obj UTF8String]);
    } else if ([key isEqual:@"text_with_tags"]) {
        //disable encoding the special characters and go on
            xmlNodeSetContent(root, BAD_CAST [obj UTF8String]);
        } else {
            xmlNewProp(root, BAD_CAST [key UTF8String], BAD_CAST [obj UTF8String]);
        }
    }
}

- (NSData *)prepareRequestBody {
    NSData *data = nil;
    xmlDocPtr doc = NULL;
    xmlNodePtr root = NULL;
    xmlNodePtr node = NULL;
    xmlNodePtr body = NULL;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    int length = 0;

    doc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST "1.0");
    root = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "SOAP-ENV:Envelope");
    xmlNewProp(root, BAD_CAST "xmlns:xsd", BAD_CAST "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    xmlNewProp(root, BAD_CAST "xmlns:xsi", BAD_CAST "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    xmlNewProp(root, BAD_CAST "xmlns:SOAP-ENC", BAD_CAST "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
    xmlNewProp(root, BAD_CAST "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle", BAD_CAST "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
    xmlNewProp(root, BAD_CAST "xmlns:SOAP-ENV", BAD_CAST "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root);
    body = xmlNewChild(root, NULL, BAD_CAST "SOAP-ENV:Body", NULL);
    node = xmlNewChild(body, NULL, BAD_CAST [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"m:%@", method] UTF8String], NULL);
    xmlNewProp(node, BAD_CAST "xmlns:m", BAD_CAST [[url absoluteString] UTF8String]);

    generate_xml(node, arguments);

    xmlDocDumpMemoryEnc(doc, (xmlChar **)&buffer, &length, "UTF-8");
    data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:length];
    xmlFree(buffer);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

    return data;
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a not elegant way. I defined my own entities - like `!#LT#!` for the `<` character. Then I simply put strings that are using such sets of characters into the XML tree and replace all occurrences of those sets with their adequate correspondents right after libxml finishes generating the XML request. Seems to do the job so far but you have to remember to check for the self-defined entities in all your user input fields in order to make sure that the user does not screw up your whole request.